# The left hand side and an assignemnt must be a variable

Tags: binary-tree

This is my code so  far, but idk why Im getting this error at the   temp.getLeft() = null; part.

```
public  Node removeLeaf(){
return removeLeaf(this.root);
}
public Node removeLeaf(Node node){
Node temp;

if(node.getLeft()==null && node.getRight()==null){
 temp = node.parent;
}
if(temp == null){
    return null;
}
if(temp.getLeft().equals(node)&& temp.getLeft()!=null){
    temp.getLeft() = null;

}

}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the language, but presumably because temp.getLeft() is a function, not a variable so assignment doesn't work that way. I'd imagine there is some kind of setter for `left` but I am not sure. (maybe `temp.getLeft().set(null)` but that is a pure guess based on the syntax of some of the other code)

Comment: `temp.getLeft()` is a method, not a variable and you cannot assign null.